# Can't install Ubuntu 18 because sda partitions not visible by installer

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Have been struggling for a while with this and had tried different troubleshootings from this forum currently I'm as in the very beginning.
While installing ubuntu from usb it doesn't give the options to select "install along..", "something else" and so. It jumps direct to [installation part where I should select the partition but it doesn't show any partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWKCk.png), thou gparted shows [all partitions included the unallocated I prepared to have ubuntu installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIb0f.png).

I'm installing it in a HP Elitebook 8540w with windows 8.1 64-bit installed. It is MBR and Legacy Bios. I have RAID and I have already disabled fast start up and hibernation. Tried to install with nomodeset with no success too.

Comment: RAID is likely to be the problem. You may need to change to AHCI. Windows may not boot though. UEFI mode would be better both for Windows and Ubuntu (I guess it's legacy because you upgraded from Windows 7?) Anyway, your machine is one of the earliest UEFI machines but even in those, preinstalled Windows 7 was almost always in Legacy. And yes, you may need `nomodeset` due to Nvidia graphics.

Comment: Changed to AHCI and to UEFI but no success. Graphics got worse with nomodeset.

Comment: You get low quality graphics with nomodeset, but once you install & then boot with nomodeset, you can install the nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository.  Is Windows fast start up off? Same for Windows 8 or 10: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Fast start up is disabled. and nomodeset selection doesn't make any difference on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to create a "new partition table" from gparted. I created a partition for windows (NTFS), another for ubuntu and a third as swap. 
Installed Windows after ubuntu and it worked fine.